# Got “TypeError: Connect() got multiple values for keyword argument 'db'” when use peewee to connect mysql

Tags: python, mysql, orm, peewee

I meet this problem when I use peewee to connect mysql first time.
The code:

```
bizDb = peewee.MySQLDatabase('dbName',host="192.168.xx.xx", user="xxx", passwd="xxx", port=8898,db="my_database_name",                       charset="utf8")
bizDb.connect()
```

then I get:

```
TypeError: Connect() got multiple values for keyword argument 'db'
```

Where is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In peewee,the MySQLDatabase's first parameter `'dbName'` is equal to `'db="my_database_name"'`,so must remove *db="my_database_name"*,if not,they conflict and you will get the error.

> btw:so freak design!